# BESClient (BIGFIX) Linux redhat

Tags: linux, puppet, redhat, satellite

I have a question about BESClient (bigfix ) config.
I want to install and config BESAgent-10.0.0.133-rhe6.x86_64 , using a puppet module to deploy it (on machines with RHEL6,7,8).
And I need know and understand, what does mean this parameter in config file besclient.config "effective date                 = Tue,%2003%20Nov%202020%2010:16:47%20+0100". I know that this is a timestamp.
I notice that , every time that puppet apply the configs on the machines, this timestamp change.
So , i don´t know if this  change in timestamp  every time that puppet run on machines, have any bad effect on config.

Answer (score 0):

The effective date only states the time stamp on which the setting was set by the bigfix client. It has no effect on the configuration itself.